# excel - .Copy() twice

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a workbook that consists of 6 worksheets. I want to save sheet 2 & 3

```
    With Excel
            .SheetsInNewWorkbook = 6
            .Workbooks.Add()
            ....

            .Worksheets(2).Copy()
            filename = "1.txt"
            .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(filename, -4158)
            .Worksheets(3).Copy()
            filename = "2.txt"
            .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(filename, -4158)
    End With
```

Upon copying the 2nd time, my application crash and return this error: Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX)). I noticed the error was due to trying to "Copy" the 2nd time, so how should I copy twice in this case?

Comment: I think that the problem is in the `.Worksheets(3)` and not the `.Copy()`. I'd verify that your workbook has the number of sheets you think it does and that the index 3 sheet is a worksheet and not a chart or something else.

Comment: @Enigmativity .Worksheets(2) and .Worksheets(3) are quite similar worksheet just with some data differences, format wise are all the same. Not only that, I tried doing .Worksheets(2).Copy twice it gives me the same error. And if I do either .Worksheets(3) or (2) only it doesn't gives me the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but `.Worksheets(2).Copy()` will open another workbook "Book2" in this case, therefore need to close it.

```
.DisplayAlerts = False
.ActiveWorkbook().Close()
```

Upon closing the copied worksheet then copy again.

```
.Worksheets(3).Copy()
filename = "2.txt"
.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(filename, -4158)
```

The full code will be

```
.Worksheets(2).Copy()
filename = "1.txt"
.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(filename, -4158)
.DisplayAlerts = False
.ActiveWorkbook().Close()
.Worksheets(3).Copy()
filename = "2.txt"
.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(filename, -4158)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
With Excel
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook = .Workbooks.Add()
    '~~> Rest of your code here
    .
    .
    .
    sourceWB.Worksheets(2).Copy
    .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\blah\test1.txt", -4158)
    sourceWB.Worksheets(3).Copy
    .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\blah\test2.txt", -4158)
End With
```

Comment: I don't have the name of work book as it isn't saved yet, the data is generated and trying to save. Right now I can Copy() twice but the 2nd copy() needs to be outside of the With block

Comment: it's not copying the worksheet properly. the 2 text file is empty.